# Intersection(s) of a line segment and a circle without trig functions?

Tags: geometry

I have a line segment with coordinates X1,Y1 and X2,Y2, and a circle center point X3,Y3 and a radius.
I want to calculate one of several results;
No intersection.
Tangency at one point.
Two intersections.
One intersection (line segment ends within circle).

Can someone provide a nice formula which provides the result without using trig functions (i.e. cos, sin, etc).

As an example of what I mean by not using trig functions;

Arc Center Point (P0) from 3 Points (P1P2P3).

X0 = (Y1^2 + X1^2 – Y3^2 –  X3^2 – (Y1 – Y3)(Y1^2 + X1^2 – Y2^2 – X2^2) / (Y1 – Y2)) / 2 / (X1 – X3 – (Y1 – Y3)(X1 – X2) / (Y1 – Y2))

Y0 = (Y1^2 + X1^2 – Y2^2 – X2^2 – 2*X0*(X1 – X2)) / (Y1 – Y2) / 2

Oh, it's not homework.  I'm a surveyor and I'd like to understand this problem for a spreadsheet application to check my software and my own satisfaction.  I've searched for days and never seen it explained completely (at my level of understanding, which is high school geometry 30 years ago).
I hope I was clear and any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks, ssz

Comment: You basically use the formula [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-LineIntersection.html). First move all points so the circle is at the origin. Then, as you have a line segment instead of a line, you need to check that the points of intersection are on the segment. Using $x= x_1+t(x_2-x_1)$ calculate $t$. If $t$ is between $0$ and $1$, the point is on the segment. For $\Delta \gt 0$, if only one point is on the segment, the segment ends inside the circle.

Comment: Are you looking for the actual points of intersection, or just a count of how many there are?

Comment: Sorry that really isn't clear the way I phrased it. I need the actual coordinates if they exist.

Comment: In that case, simply solving for the intersections will give you a straightforward formula, though I’m not sure that I’d call it “nice.” Then again, I wouldn’t call the arc center point formula you’ve got “nice,” either ;)

Comment: I appreciate your efforts but perhaps i haven't made it clear that I'm not a mathematician.

Comment: @amd gave a beautifully concise answer which I just upvoted (+1). I suggest you leave a comment to his post asking if he could make it more user-friendly for a non-mathematician.

Answer (score 2):

Let $P_1$ and $P_2$ be the endpoints of the line segment, $C$ the center of the circle and $R$ its radius. The line segment can be parameterized as $(1-t)P_1+tP_2$, $0\le t\le1$. The condition that a point on the line segment is also on the circle can then be expressed as $$\|(1-t)P_1+tP_2-C\|^2=R^2.$$ Expanding this equation in terms of coordinates produces a quadratic in $t$, which I assume you know how to solve via, say, the quadratic formula. Real roots of this quadratic that lie in the interval $[0,1]$ give you the points of intersection of the circle and line segment.